# Random image appear when website is loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 pictures for my website, and i want it to load one of them whem the website loads.

I have tried using some javascript. But i am quite new to all this.

This is how i am think i want to make it.

```
<div class="image">
Show one of 2 images here.
</div>


    <script>
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;    
    if(r < 51) { 
       SHOW IMAGE 1
    }
    else {
        SHOWIMAGE 2
    }
    </sccript>
```

So i was hoping someone could teach me how to actually turn this into functional code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the src attribute of an image directly using javascript, then use Math.random like you expected to pick between different image urls.

With an image tag with id 'random_image':

```
// images from wikipedia featured images/articles 2015-03-03
var img = document.getElementById('random_image');
if (Math.random() > .5) {
    img.src = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/45/Bradford1911.jpg/266px-Bradford1911.jpg';
} else {
    img.src = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ae/Pitta_sordida_-_Sri_Phang_Nga.jpg/720px-Pitta_sordida_-_Sri_Phang_Nga.jpg';
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/8zd5509u/

Comment: Hey @CollinGreen This worked perfectly for me! Thanks.
Now i am going to add a timer to the script, i know how to do this with timeout. But is there a way to makes so it fades out, instead of such a "hard" switch. Or is this a lot more work?

Comment: @FrederikLund - it isn't too bad to do manually in vanilla javascript, but it is super easy if you are using a library (like jquery has a built in fade function). Either way, you should start a new question (and accept this answer if you feel like it solved the problem for you).

Answer (score 0):

*1.way:*

```
var _img = document.getElementById('id1');
var newImg = new Image;
newImg.onload = function() {
    _img.src = this.src;
}
newImg.src = 'http://www.something.blabla.....';
```

---

*another:*

```
function preload(images) {
    if (document.images) {
        var i = 0;
        var imageArray = new Array();
        imageArray = images.split(',');
        var imageObj = new Image();
        for(i=0; i<=imageArray.length-1; i++) {
            //document.write('<img src="' + imageArray[i] + '" />');// Write to page (uncomment to check images)
            imageObj.src=imageArray[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the  of each web page, add the following code after you've called the main JavaScript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
preload('image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg');
</script>
```